# requirejs with vue.js will raise "Vue is not defined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, requirejs

I use following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>console.log(Vue)</script>
```

it will raise:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
```

following code will work well:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>console.log(Vue)</script>
```

following code will also work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script>
  requirejs(["../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"], (Vue) => {
    window.Vue = Vue;
    console.log(Vue)
  })
</script>
```

**I just wanna know, why requirejs cause window.Vue = null**, it's there way to make importing Vue with requirejs same with importing Vue without requirejs?

Comment: Have you thought about modernizing your build? Why are you using requirejs still? It was deprecated before Vue even existed! Vue CLI can generate you a good project

Answer (score 0):

I find the simple solution, just import vue.js before requirejs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log(Vue)
</script>
```

I guess requirejs override some function that vue init need, so window.Vue is not init